# Editing WooCommerce coupon message

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

How do I correct/edit the alignment/contents of the coupon message (refer to the screenshot) that pops up when a user enters the coupon code at the cart checkout page in WordPress?

[image: coupon message]

Comment: Post your code for better response from the community.

Comment: share site url also

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the template inside the woocommerce plugin's template folder.

Then create a woocommerce folder in your child theme, and copy the template there (same folder strucure).

Finally you make changes to your child theme's coupon template.

[Read the comments for this file](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/checkout/form-coupon.php)